# Set Windows 10 Long Date, with capitalized month word

Tags: windows-10, regional-settings

I'm using Portuguese format in region and language settings. In Windows 7 i have the following long date example: "segunda-feira, 13 de Setembro de 2021", but in Windows 10 i have the month name not capitalized, and it's showing like this: "segunda-feira, 13 de setembro de 2021".
In Windows 7 i have "Setembro" and in Windows 10 i have "setembro" (September in english).
How can i set month to be capitalized in Windows 10?

EDIT:

[image: Region Settings Print Screen]

---

[image: Region Format Print Screen]

If i change the format to English (United States), the month is capitalized.

Thanks,
JP.

Comment: Can you show your format from regional settings, please?

Comment: @spikey_richie, i have edit my previous post with a print screen

Comment: This might be a bug in Windows, or a specific design for your region... For UK, `dddd, dd MMMM yyyy` shows (for today) "Monday, 13 September 2021". If I change to Portugese (Portugal), I see the long date format as `dddd, d' de 'MMMM' de 'yyyy` which renders it all in lowercase. Uppercase M, D or Y denotes start with a capital, but it doesn't work for your region.

Comment: @spikey_richie, is there any way to force the month to be capitalized in Windows 10? In Windows 7 this works fine.

Comment: I tried `dddd, d MMMM yyyy`, but it still renders in lowercase. I'm not sure if it's because of this https://www.google.com/search?q=why+are+months+lowercase+in+spanish There may be a workaround, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, in our vocabulary months have changed the first letter to lowercase a 
 time ago, but at the begging it was like in english. But in my particular case and because of a format issue i have, i need to change this first letter to uppercase.

Comment: I'd suggest that you update your original posting with the information in your last comment. I'd include some more info about the problematic application also (incl version), and what issues the lowercase formatting causes. Even if there was no way to do this in Windows itself, another user of the application might have a workaround for you.

Comment: @Peregrino69, thanks for the reply, in that case the workaround must be made by myself, i was trying to solve this issue in a easy way,