# Formatting of dates (Days / Months) on Windows 10 / 11

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, date, locale

I know that we have a certain amount of control in the operating system to adjust the way dates are displayed.

This issue relates to how some of the locales display:

- Days
- Months

For some locales it shows these as all lowercase and not Title Case (as in the English locale).

I have been trying to find out if there is any way to drill in to change the days of the week / months of the year to be Title Case for a given local?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1675933/set-windows-10-long-date-with-capitalized-month-word Seems like it is not possible.

Comment: Exactly what are your date settings?

Comment: @harrymc It is not my PC. The user has Portuguese set which formats to lowercase. I guess much like the linked question.